# C# Catch Progress From DotNet EXE Installer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, installation, uwp

I am making many applications (mostly UWP), I am also going to be creating a UWP installer app. Kind of like the Microsoft store. But to install the installer UWP, I am going to be creating a self-contained WPF EXE. This would install the installer and additionally check for dotnet on the client machine. If dotnet is present then everything is fine and it continues along with the installation. But if dotnet is not installed, then it will have a link so the user can install it manually and an option for the WPF app to do it. I know how to download the installer and run it in the background without the UI, but how would I get the progress of the dotnet installation and display it in my own custom installer.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

P.S. All my applications will be using .Net Core 5+ (Or .Net Core 6 when it comes out).

Comment: I would not expect it to be possible to extract progress from an third party installer that is run without a UI.

Comment: @JonasH Is there a way to make a custom dotnet installer, one that simply downloads the required files? Could this be able to give the progress of downloading? Also, what would the installer have to do? Like what registry entries or path changes? Which files would have to be downloaded? Thanks so much!

Comment: I would not recommend trying to build your own .net installer, it would likely be fragile. Consider building self-contained applications instead, possibly with some de-duplication system if you want to save space.

Comment: But UWP? Self-contained? .Net Native for some reason doesn't work either. If you were a customer, would you be fine with not seeing a progress bar and instead just seeing "Installing .Net Core [Version]..." Or would you be fine with my wife just downloading the installer but you (the user) sees the .net installer? Basically the WPF would just download and run the dotnet installer. Would you be fine with either one of the options as a user? Thanks!

Comment: By default, windows should ask if the .net version should be downloaded if it is missing when the application is launched, and I would much prefer that than using some third party installer of unknown quality modifying the registry etc. There is an option for .Net core apps to [bundle all needed .net core dependencies to avoid framework dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained), at the cost of a larger installation package. As far as I understand this should be independent of UWP, since that is an OS API, not a .net core API.

Comment: No... UWP apps need the .net runtime. The only option is .net native which compiles it to native but for some reason, it doesn't work. What do you mean of unknown quality? It would be the installer downloaded from the dotnet website.

Comment: I wouldn't be modifying the registry at all. The dotnet installer that I downloaded would be modifying it.